# using interface and composition in java - reuse code with different variables

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, composition

I have a problem during trying to do reuse code.
I want to use main interface with two classes, but some of the methods have same implements, so I decided to use compostion.
I mean, to declare instance of the "a" class and do on the method:

```
void do_some()
a.do_some()
```

the problem is that the function related to some data members.
for example:

```
 public class Locker implements GeneralStorage {
    private final int current_capacity;

  public int getAvailableCapacity(){
        return current_capacity;
      }
}

public class LongTermStorage implements GeneralStorage {
    private final int current_capacity;
    private Locker locker=New Locker();
       public int getAvailableCapacity(){
           return locker.getAvailableCapacity
```

what can I do? (I want to return LongTermStorage.current_capacity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so, but it'd be better if you create an instance for composition at your constructor. So it would be like this:

```
public class Locker implements GeneralStorage {
  private final int current_capacity;

  public int getAvailableCapacity(){
    return current_capacity;
  }
}

public class LongTermStorage implements GeneralStorage {
  private Locker locker;

  public LongTermStorage() {
    locker = new Locker();
  }

  public int getAvailableCapacity(){
    return locker.getAvailableCapacity();
  }
}
```

So, you will reuse `Locker` methods and also its props.

Answer (score 0):

If LongTermStorage is a special kind of Locker you can use inheritance and let LongTermStorage extend from Locker. This way you only have to implement the methods which are different:

```
public class LongTermStorage  extends Locker {
    // No need to implement getAvailableCapacity() as the one from Locker is fine

    // TODO: implement other stuff specific for LongTermStorage
}
```

Implicitly `LongTermStorage` also implements the `GeneralStorage` interface so you can use it wherever you want to use `GeneralStorage`

Comment: longTermStorage is not a kind of Locker, it has another constructer. So I think the firsr option is the best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java well, but do this instead of what was recommended above:

```
interface GeneralStorage {
    void addProduct(Product product);
    void removeProduct(Product product);
    void close();
}

public class Locker implements GeneralStorage {
  private Product[] products;

  public void addProduct(Product product) {...};
  public void removeProduct(Product product) {...};
  public void close() {...};
}

public class LongTermStorage implements GeneralStorage {
  private GeneralStorage storage;

  public LongTermStorage(GeneralStorage storage) {
    this.storage = storage;
  }
  
  public void addProduct(Product product) {
    // some kind of logic
    storage.addProduct(product)
  };
  public void removeProduct(Product product) {...};
  public void close() {...};
}

GeneralStorage storage = new LongTermStorage(new Locker())
```

Don't couple `LongTermStorage` to `Locker` by calling `new` in the constructer.